# Java regex for matching multiple keys in a string

Tags: java, regex

Consider an input string like

```
Number ONE=1 appears before TWO=2 and THREE=3 comes before FOUR=4 and FIVE=5
```

and the regular expression

```
\b(TWO|FOUR)=([^ ]*)\b
```

Using this regular expression, the following code can extract the 2 specific key-value pairs out of the 5 total ones (i.e., only some predefined key-value pairs should be extracted).

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String input = "Number ONE=1 appears before TWO=2 and THREE=3 comes before FOUR=4 and FIVE=5";
    String regex = "\\b(TWO|FOUR)=([^ ]*)\\b";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
      System.out.println("\t" + matcher.group(1) + " = " + matcher.group(2));
    }
  }
```

More specifically, the `main()` method above prints

```
TWO = 2
FOUR = 4
```

but every time `find()` is invoked, the whole regular expression is evaluated for the part of the string remaining after the latest match, left to right.

Also, if the keys are not mutually distinct (or, if a regular expression with overlapping matches was used in the place of each key), there will be multiple matches. For instance, if the regex becomes

```
\b(O.*?|T.*?)=([^ ]*)\b
```

the above method yields

```
ONE = 1
TWO = 2
THREE = 3
```

If the regex was not fully re-evaluated but each alternative part was somehow examined once (or, if an appropriately modified regex was used), the output would have been

```
ONE = 1
TWO = 2
```

So, two questions:

1. Is there a more efficient way of extracting a selected set of unique keys and their values, compared to the original regular expression?
2. Is there a regular expression that can match every alternative part of the OR (`|`) sub-expression exactly once and not evaluate it again?

Comment: Just to understand where you're coming from... Is this question out of intellectual curiosity, or are you actually worried that evaluating each branch of the OR is too slow for you?

Comment: All of that and more, with a real problem as the starting point. Namely, extracting a predefined set of keys (and their values) from long strings that have numerous other key-value pairs that should be ignored an interesting and not rare use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Java Returns a Match Position: You can Use Dynamically-Generated Regex on Remaining Substrings**

With the understanding that it can be generalized to a more complex and useful scenario, let's take a variation on your first example: `\b(TWO|FOUR|SEVEN)=([^ ]*)\b`

You can use it like this:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\b(TWO|FOUR|SEVEN)=([^ ]*)\\b");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(yourString);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    String theMatch = regexMatcher.group();
    String FoundToken =  = regexMatcher.group(1);
    String EndPosition = regexMatcher.end();
}
```

You could then:

- Test the value contained by `FoundToken`
- Depending on that value, dynamically generate a regex testing for the remaining possible tokens. For instance, if you found `FOUR`, your new regex would be `\\b(TWO|SEVEN)=([^ ]*)\\b`
- Using `EndPosition`, apply that regex to the end of the string.

**Discussion**

- This approach would serve your goal of not re-evaluating parts of the `OR` that have already matched.
- It also serves your goal of avoiding duplicates.
- Would that be faster? Not in this simple case. But you said you are dealing with a real problem, and it will be a valid approach in some cases.

Comment: Yes, regeneration of the regular expression for the remainder of the parsed string should work, as you suggest. Please edit to make the code compilable (foundToken and endPosition need to be declared somewhere). It would be a bit more exciting if there was a way of doing this in "one pass", but +1 for the contribution anyway. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I had three implicit `String something = null;` off-screen, outside the code block. :) Just added `String` to the three results.

Comment: Sure. Just being pedantic. :-)

Comment: FYI: Changed the `TWO|FOUR` example to `TWO|FOUR|SEVEN` so the dynamic nature of the regexes used is clearer to a later reader. Also expanded discussion of the approach.

Comment: By the way, few engines return a match position, so this is one of these rare cases where Java regex shines.

Comment: True, this is a very useful feature to have.

Comment: +1 as always a detailed analysis with good alternative approaches.